# How to output an html file in an R function?

Tags: r, knitr

I am interested in writing a function where it takes a data frame as an input and returns an html page via knitr as an output based on the information in the data frame.

Here is sort of the psuedocode of the function that I wanted to write:

```
htmlOuput <- function(Df) {
   newDf<-someManipulation(Df)
   meltedDf<-melt(Df)
   g<-ggplot(meltedDf)
   return (html(g)) # This is the part that I am not sure about
  }
```

Is there a way to output an html page as a function output via knitr ?

Comment: `browseURL(tempfile(f = '.html'))`

Comment: `g` is a stored ggplot object, not a data.frame.

Comment: I know that `g` is a ggplot object, so I want the plot generated through ggplot rendered in the html file

Comment: @rawr Isn't browseURL to load an HTML file, I wanted to render the plot that I generate into an html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found that calling an rmarkdown file to render within a function to be the best option.

```
htmlOuput <- function(Df,meta = NULL, cacheable = NA) {
    rmarkdown::render('./report.rmd',params=list(output_file = report.html))
}
```

Where the `report.rmd` will contain the manipulation of the data frame

```
newDf<-someManipulation(Df)
meltedDf<-melt(Df)
g<-ggplot(meltedDf)
g
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you took the hard way.

An easy approach would be to use [htmlTable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/tables.html)

I have used that to export to html and it is easy to use.

Comment: htmlTable seem to only work for tables, but what I am looking for is a html report mainly with figures from the given data frame